React pattern to conditionally render forms inside Card component and use Card.Footer for saving them all
I have a quite common React Card component that I can use like this:
...
<Card>
    <Card.Title>
        ...
    </Card.Title>
    ...
    <Card.Footer>
        ...
    </Card.Footer>
</Card>
...

It works just fine when filling it in with "normal" components.
But now I want to display a component inside it based on a tab state variable (0, 1 or 2), so I use it like this:
...
<Card>
    ...
    {
        tab === 0 ? <ComponentA /> : 
            tab === 1 ? <ComponentB /> :
                tab === 2 ? <ComponentC /> : 
                    null
    }
    <Card.Footer>
        ...
    </Card.Footer>
</Card>

The problem is that Components A, B and C consist of forms with their respective Save Changes buttons and associated logic. They are independent from each other and even the parent Card. And I want those Save buttons to be located inside the Card.Footer subcomponent. That is, "exposing" save buttons and behaviour to the parent Card component...
The question arises because I think this pattern seems to be very common to me (every UI library has a Card component with Header, Footer and so on...
So... Do I have to change the design and rethink the structure?
What is the React way of resolving this?
Thanks in advance.
